# Entity framework - storing various types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building a workflow for some forms, that would route to users for approval.  I have an abstract 'FormBase' class which stores a LinkedList of 'Approver' objects and has some helpers that modify the approver list, move the form to the next person and so on.  These helpers are all 'virtual' so that a given form can override them with custom behaviours.

From this 'base' will come instances of various forms, each of which will differ in the data it contains.  It'll be the normal set of lists, strings, and numeric values you'd find in a normal form.  So I might have

```
 class MaterialForm : FormBase
 class CustomerForm : FormBase
```

etc, and a new instance is created when a user creates and submits a form.

I'd like to persist the field details of in EF6 (or 5), in a flexible way so I could create more forms deriving from FormBase without too much fiddling.  Ideally I'd like all behaviour specific to that form type to live in the MaterialForm derived class.  I figure I can't persist this derived class to EF (unless I'm wrong!).  I'm considering:

a) JSonifying the field details, and storing them as a string in the class which gets stored to EF.  I'd probably do the same for the approver list, and each time I need to modify the list I'd pull them out, modify the list and push them back.

b) Including a 'FormData' property in my abstract class, then including a derived version of that in each concrete implementation (eg MaterialFormData, CustomerFormData).  However, the abstract class didn't seem to like my use of a derived type in this way.  Also unclear is how the DbSets would be setup in this case as you'd probably need a new table for each type.

I feel I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about how the 'real' classes relate to those stored in EF.  What would you recommend as an architecture for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to Entity Framework you have three supported models for inheritance: Table Per Type (TPT), Table Per Hierarchy (TPH), and Table Per Concrete Class (TPC).

The use of TPC is generally avoided, and choosing between the other two comes down to several factors including performance and flexibility. There is a great article outlining the differences [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx).

I'd also recommend reading [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96185/Table-Per-Hierarchy-Inheritance-in-Entity-Framewor) for more information and examples on how these patterns work.

However, in your example it sounds like the issue is at the 'design' stage in terms of coming up with a suitable 'model' for your application. My advice is that, if you feel the class structure you have come up with can not accurately represent the model you are working with, you either need to change the structure; your model is massively complex; or you are constrained by an outside system (a database schema that you have no way of changing for example).

In this case, have you considered doing a class diagram? Even if you use the EF designer, try and visualize the model, as that's usually the best way of determining where improvements can be made, and also gives you a good start in the design (especially if you're going code first).

Try that, and post that back here if necessary. We can then help redesign the model if required. My feeling is that there's nearly always some good way of representing your requirement with a decent OO perspective, and it's best to analyse that before looking at more elaborate options! The key here is to avoid thinking of creating new class types dynamically if that can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Nick.  Good links.